# Upload files not working using jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, file-upload

**Problem:**

To set session variable and redirect user to different PHP-page once upload of .txt file has been completed using jQuery File Upload.

**HTML code (upload.php):**

```
<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<!-- The global progress bar -->
<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

**jQuery code (upload.php):**

```
<script>    
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        // Server-side upload handler:
        var url = 'process.php';

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
            done: function (e, data) {
                $(this).delay(2000, function(){
                    window.location = "explorer.php";
                });
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

**PHP upload script (process.php):**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $folder      = 'upload';

    if (!empty($_FILES))
    {
        // Set temporary name
        $tmp    = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

        // Set target path and file name
        $target = $folder . '/' . $_FILES['files']['name'];

        // Upload file to target folder
        $status = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);

        if ($status)
        {
            // Set session with txtfile name
            $_SESSION['txtfile'] = $_FILES['files']['name'];
        }
    }
?>
```

**Desired output:**

- Text file should be uploaded to folder /upload - which currently has chmod 777
- Session of text file name should be assigned to the variable $_SESSION['txtfile']
- Redirect user once upload is done to the file "explorer.php"

**EDIT: SOLVED. Final code above!**

Comment: any error messages? what currently happens when you run this?

Comment: No error messages but nothing gets uploaded either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters...

Notice your `input` name is `files[]` and has attribute `multiple`. This means that you are sending an array of files to the server so to reference them in php, you'll need something like this:

`$_FILES['files']['name'][0]`

for the first file.

Also, I have found that `move_uploaded_file()` likes full paths for the destination, try tacking on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

To send information back to jQuery you would want to use `echo json_encode()` like so...

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => 'your message here'
));
```

In your `done` function the data can be accessed like this:

```
done: function(e, data){
     console.log(data.status);
     console.log(data.message);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this solved the uploading issue. Now the file does get uploaded. But how do I send back a response to jQuery to move the person to "explorer.php"?

Comment: you could send back html, use a script to set window.location, if your current method is not working...

Comment: Not sure I follow, I suspect that the "done:" part should be modified. But how would I return an answer from process.php back to jQuery?

Comment: Shouldn't I just be able to put window.location = "explorer.php"; in done:? I tried it but didn't work. Updated with new code.

Comment: you'll most likely need to provide a full address for the new location, or at least "../explorer.php".....im guessing

Comment: I tried to do: window.location.href = "http://full.address.here/explorer.php"; but with no success.

Comment: It could be due to the form submitting, try adding `return false;` right after your window.location line

Comment: Updated jQuery code with your suggestion but still no redirect.

Comment: not sure whats going on, have you tried using `http://www.google.com` for the url to verify that it works

Comment: Progress bar gets completed, file gets uploaded, but redirect does not fire. Feels like I have written everything completely.

Comment: Solution was very easy. Remove "dataType: json" and I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674999/jquery-fileupload-doesnt-trigger-done - no idea why.

Comment: One last question: is it possible to add a delay before "done:"? Just 2-3 second after uploading is complete. EDIT: managed to figure it out by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704553/jquery-delay-function - final code updated as well.

Comment: that would do it, if you arent using echo json_encode()....and for the delay, you could wrap everything inside of a `setTimeout()`

Comment: I wrapped it up with the delay() instead and works like a charm. Highly appreciate your help, keep up the good work.